# python for loop isnt recognising int inside a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to change the contents of a list changing every `-127` for a `1` and `-128` for a `0`. However I struggle to find why my code does not change the digits as intended or even recognizes them:

```
my_file = open("log.txt", "r")
content = my_file.read()
my_file.close()

clean_contnet = content.split("\n")


for idx, x in enumerate(clean_contnet):

     if x == -127 or x == -128:
        if x == -127:
            clean_contnet[idx] = 1

        else:
            clean_contnet[idx] = 0

     else:
        print("no -127 or -128 detected")

print(clean_contnet)
```

The (shortened) contents of `'log.txt'` are as follows

> ```
> 0
> -127
> 1
> -128
> 0
> -127
> 1
> -128
> 0
> -127
> 1
> ```

Comment: You can debug this sort of thing by printing the "repr" representation of the values you are comparing. `print(f"comparing {x!r}")`. It will show for instance `'-127'` indicating a string instead of an int.

Answer (score 4):

`clean_contnet` is a list of strings, not ints. You should do `x = int(x)` before checking its value.

Answer (score 4):

You never convert your read in string data into integers - comparing a string with a number never will lead to a `True` statement.

Change:

```
# convert read in numbers to string - will crash if non numbers inside
clean_content = [int(part) for part in content.split("\n") if part]
```

or compare vs string:

```
if x in ("-127","-128"):
    clean_content[idx] = 1 if x == "-127" else 0
```

This uses a ternary expression - see [Does Python have a ternary conditional operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator)

Comment: Next step would be to drop `my_file.read()` since a text file is iterable. Then we can create the list with: `clear_content = [int(line) for line in my_file]` (and an optional `if line.strip()` if we expect empty lines).

Comment: @Matthias you wouldn't want to use open without context handler `with open( ..) as f:` anyway  - so you are right, plenty of room for more improvement